# jQuery $.post-function | data-processing function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I am new in web development, but having years of experience in traditional development, e.g. using Java, C and ABAP, under my belt.

I am trying to create a pretty simple Login-functionality, but struggling with jQuery's `$.post()`-functionality.

In the below seen code, the `alert("test")`-function in the data-processing part of `$.post()` doesn´t seem to get executed, after I submit the form `form_login`. I guess the problem is with how I connected the JavaScript-function `login_attempt()` with the submitting of form `form_login`.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>

 <script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 function login_attempt(){
  $.post("login.php", $("#form_login").serialize(), function(data){alert("test");},html);
 }
 </script>

</head>
<body>
 <h1>Login-Form</h1> 
 <form id="form_login" method="post" onsubmit="return login_attempt()">
  <p><label for="id_username">Username: </label><input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" width="20"></label></p>
  <p><label for="id_password">Password: </label><input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" width="10"></label></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit_login"></p>
 </form>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `login_attempt` is now triggered when submitting the form and then after that the form is submitted as well since the `login_attempt` function does not tell the form to stop submitting in the regular way. Therefor the page reloads before the actual callback of the `post` method could do anything.

Add `return false;` as last line of the login_attempt function to tell the form it should not submit in the regular way.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. Btw, is this a common way to handle form-posts with JavaScript?

Comment: used to be, but most devs now avoid using onevent attributes.

Comment: Yes its not uncommon, however it is more elegant to add the onsubmit in javascript using $('#formid').on('submit', function())

Comment: When I try it that way, the function is called when the site is loaded.